# Spark 1.5.2: Accessing a dataframe inside another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Sql dataframe `df1` with the following contents:

```
   id value
   10   100
   20   200
```

Now I have another dataframe `df2` which looks like this:

```
id  old_value
10  800
20  200
```

Now I want to update `df2` based on the contents of `df1` such as:

```
val df3 = df2.withColumn('new_value' udf_function(col(id), col(old_value))
```

where `udf_function` is defined as:

```
val udf_function = udf((id: Integer, value:Integer) => {
                      df1[id] - value // pseudo code
})
```

How do I execute `df1[id]` inside the above udf  function? I expect to see  `df3` created like:

```
id old_value new_value
10  800        700
20  200        0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a DataFrame inside of another DataFrame transformation. The only solution that you have is to join on id to create a new DataFrame then you can call your udf on. The following example uses actually a simple operation on those joint columns :

```
scala> val df1 = Seq((10, 100), (20, 200)).toDF("id", "value")
// df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, value: int]

scala> val df2 = Seq((10, 800), (20, 200)).toDF("id", "old_value")
// df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, old_value: int]

scala> val df3 = df2.join(df1, df1("id") === df2("id")).drop(df1("id")).withColumn("new_value", $"value" - $"old_value")
// df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, old_value: int, value: int, new_value: int]

scala> df3.show()
// +---+---------+-----+---------+                                                 
// | id|old_value|value|new_value|
// +---+---------+-----+---------+
// | 10|      800|  100|     -700|
// | 20|      200|  200|        0|
// +---+---------+-----+---------+

scala> val df3 = df2.join(df1, df1("id") === df2("id")).drop(df1("id")).withColumn("new_value", $"old_value" - $"value")
// df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, old_value: int, value: int, new_value: int]

scala> df3.show()
// +---+---------+-----+---------+
// | id|old_value|value|new_value|
// +---+---------+-----+---------+
// | 10|      800|  100|      700|
// | 20|      200|  200|        0|
// +---+---------+-----+---------+
```